# Проверка в SQL базе

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

Здравствуйте ! Я тут наткнулся на проблему и на форуме уже есть подобные решения , но мне они не помогли , вот мне нужно проверить наличие логина в таблице SQL Код:
На переменные которых не существует не обращайте внимания , я урезал код.

```
elseif(isset($_POST["login"])) {
$login = $_POST["login"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
mysqli_query($mysql_con, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`, `password`, `email`, `IP`, `Browser`, `Date`, `City`) VALUES ('', '$login', '$password', '$email', '$ipaddress', '$browser', '$Date', '$result');");
```

Насколько я видел на форуме есть решение наподобие

SELECT 'login' FROM 'users' WHERE 'login' = "$login';

Но я не совсем понял , подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем записывать новый логин в таблицу (кстати, поле логи должно быть уникальным индексом), нужно проверить, а не существует ли уже такой логин в таблице. Для этого нужно посмотреть вернет ли селект данные:

```
SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = $login;
```

Если селект вернул не пустой набор данных - такой логин уже в базе есть и надо сообщить об этом например ошибкой.

Comment: А можете пожалуйста более подробно написать код ?

Comment: Вот тут все отлично расписано http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php Внизу есть куча примеров

Comment: то есть mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 - есть логин ?

Comment: @VIP300100 да, именно так

Comment: Помоги , тут вроде сделал , но что ввожу имеющийся логин , что не имеющийся , всё равно не добавляется в таблицу// REQUEST
$ifses = "SELECT 'login' FROM 'users' WHERE 'login' = '$login'";

// test
if (mysqli_num_rows($ifses) {
 // HAVE LOGIN
 echo "Такой пользователь существует !";
}
else {
 // NOT HAVE LOGIN
 mysqli_query($mysql_con, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`, `password`, `email`, `IP`, `Browser`, `Date`, `City`) VALUES ('', '$login', '$password', '$email', '$ipaddress', '$browser', '$Date', '$result');");
}

Comment: @VIP300100 так ты перед тем как считать количество строк, которые вернул select, сам select выполни и считай строке в $result. $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")

Comment: Ух... Смотри , я не понял , что означает у тебя $result ? Ты им заменил мою строку $ifses ?

Comment: $ifses = "SELECT 'login' FROM 'users' WHERE 'login' = $login"; $result = mysqli_query($mysql_con, $ifses); $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);  if ($count > 0) { логин уже есть } else { логина нет }

Comment: Ладно , спасибо конечно , но всё равно никак не получается , даже твой код не работает ,  что я и ввожу который есть , что и которого нет , добавляется в любом случае. Спасибо !

Comment: Переиенную $login вытащи из строки

Comment: $ifses = "SELECT 'login' FROM 'users' WHERE 'login' = " . $login; $result = mysqli_query($mysql_con, $ifses); $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); if ($count > 0) { логин уже есть } else { логина нет }

Comment: Ты выведи результирующий select-запрос например echo $ifses; перед его выполнением. И посмотри как он вообще выглядит.

Comment: @Machoz А что делать если при выводе echo ничего не выводит ? Я про вообще то есть любые фразы

Comment: Значит скорее всего скрипт по условию не попадает на эту строку. Пробуй так. $ifses = "SELECT 'login' FROM 'users' WHERE 'login' = '" . $login . "'"; echo $ifses; exit;

Comment: Он должен выводиться где ? У меня вот сайт : https://vip300100.000webhostapp.com/SocHack%20Register

Comment: Эм... А домашний сервер установить никак? Например этот https://ospanel.io

Comment: А что тут не так ?

Comment: Он должен выводиться прямо в страницу. Разбирайся. Если у тебя команда exit не отработала, то твой код явно не попадает в эту секцию. Вообщем отлаживай...